# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, macos-big-sur, valet

I have problem with my php on mac, previously I had 2 php versions php7.3 and php7.2. for some reason I uninstalled them then reinstall php7.2. when I run `brew link php@7.2` and `php -v` I'm getting message `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php` I already run command `brew update brew upgrade php reinstall php@7.2` but I'm getting same error message.

Answer (score 17):

Had the same problem, after switching php@7.4 (back) to php 7.2

Reinstall php@7.2 didn't help. What did help was:

```
brew reinstall tidy-html5
```

Answer (score 15):

```
brew reinstall gd
```

Good one from [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13093603/thomas) with the tip [dyld[45923]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219126/dyld45923-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-libavif-lib-libavif-15-dylib/77222642#77222642)

This cleared up errors of `/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib` and the likes.

Comment: this is the solution that works for me

Comment: Same for me. Thanks 

Comment: Worked for me as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

OK, I am sure this is not the right way to do it, but it worked for me. I believe it may have to do with PHP 7.2 reaching end of life and things not installing correctly as it's now deprecated upstream.

I went ahead and looked at the `/usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/` folder and indeed `libtidy.5.dylib` was not there... but `libtidy.5.8.0.dylib` was. So I just symlinked the dylib I had to `libtidy.5.dylib` like so:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib
```

And that worked great!

There were a few other libraries that needed the same treatment within the `/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/` folder, but it was the same idea. Look in the folder where it's failing to find the library and it might just be named with a more specific version number. `ln -s` them (or even `cp` or `mv` them) to match the file that PHP is looking for and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i had to uninstall php@7.2 with brew. If you have some related configuration in ./bash_profile o similar, dont forget check it in order to avoid misconfiguration issues